# How to use checked and checkedValue with Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I use this html and bind it to a Knockout model. The checkedValue works as intended. But I cannot figure out how to combine it with checked so I also can set a css to highlight the row html element.

```
<div class="row" data-bind="css: { highlight: whatShouldThisBe }">
   <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.selectedRows" />
   {{ text }}
</div>
```

How do I get the checked state for each row model?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   css: { highlight: $root.selectedRows().indexOf($data)>-1 }
```

Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/luisvsilva/2huba5xw/3/